# How can I stop Qt::ForbiddenCursor from appearing during a drag?

Tags: qt, qt4, drag-and-drop, x11

I'm implementing a drag and drop interface with **Qt** across **X11** and **Windows**. The interface handles events such that it is not illegal for a user to drop a dragged object on an area which can't handle drops.

In this case, [`Qt::IgnoreAction`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#DropAction-enum) should therefore **not** be treated as an incorrect potential action. To communicate this fact to the user I need a way to stop [`Qt::ForbiddenCursor`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt.html#CursorShape-enum) from displaying if the current `Qt::DropAction` is `Qt::IgnoreAction`.

There are three ways I can see to achieve this (in order of preference):

- To override the [`QCursor`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcursor.html) used for a drag with `Qt::IgnoreAction` to something other than `Qt::ForbiddenCursor`.
- To override the bitmap used for `Qt::ForbiddenCursor`. This is pretty dirty but would be an acceptable solution as long as I don't have to delve into OS-specific configuration.
- To override the call made by Qt when a drag leaves a valid drop area (I assume that Qt does the equivalent of `QDropEvent::setDropAction(Qt::IgnoreAction)` in this case).

Could anyone suggest ways to acheive any of the above?

---

**Note:** I have also attempted to use `QApplication::setOverrideCursor()` just before calling `QDrag::exec()`. This doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Just courious, but why you want to cheat on user?

Comment: Check if QDragEnterEvent comes to application itself (install event filter on QApplication object). if it does, simply accept it and cursor will appear normal

Comment: Good shout Kamil, an obvious solutionwhen you think about it... I've just tested and this will do the job. It's a little dirty, but it works! If I don't hear any other suggestions, please submit this as an answer so I can award the bounty. How do you mean 'cheat on user' by the way?

Comment: Well you cheat on user that this operation is allowed (will perform an action) but it wont? Or maybe you want to "filter" this drop event and perform some action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `QDragEnterEvent` comes to application itself (install event filter on `QApplication` object). If it does, simply accept it and cursor will appear normal.